# I am trying to do a score that increase on ball collision with brick

Tags: c#

I am doing a game in Unity for a school project.
I need to increase the score when the ball collides with brick. What I am doing wrong please? Below is the code that I tried to use. Score starts at zero but never goes more than 1. Any help of how I can fix this issue please?

```
public class Brick : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public int hitPoint = 3;
        public GameObject explosion;

        public GameObject heart;
        [Range(0f, 1f)]
        public float percentage;
        float randNum;
        public float fallSpeed = 8.0f;

        public Sprite OneHits;
        public Sprite TwoHits;
        public Sprite ThreeHits;

        public Text ScoreText;
        private int points;
        GameObject ball;

        void Start()
        {
          ball = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ball");        
        }

        void Update()
        {
            ScoreText.text = "Score " + points ;
            randNum = Random.Range(0f, 1f);

            if (hitPoint == 1)
            {
                this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = OneHits;
            }
            if (hitPoint == 2)
            {
                this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = TwoHits;
            }
            if (hitPoint == 3)
            {
                this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = ThreeHits;
            }
         }


        private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
        {
            if (collision.gameObject.tag == "ball")
            {
                ball = collision.gameObject;
                hitPoint--;
                points++;

                if (hitPoint <= 0)
                {
                    Destroy(this.gameObject);
                    Instantiate(explosion, transform.position, transform.rotation);

                    if (randNum < percentage)
                    {
                        Instantiate(heart, transform.position, transform.rotation);
                    }               
                }            
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How many bricks are in the scene?

Comment: `points` shouldn't be a property for a `Brick`, bricks don't have points. Put it in a different class like `Game` or `Player`, since it/he is the one having points.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things wrong with your code.

If you destroy the game object the script is running on the script will stop, so I would move your destroy command to the end of your method.

I am guessing that you dont want points to be different for each brick, I would move points to another class called scoreboard or something. For the time being I made points static. This means that only one copy of this variable exists and if one brick adds a point it gets reflected across all bricks.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int hitPoint = 3;
    public GameObject explosion;

    public GameObject heart;
    [Range(0f, 1f)]
    public float percentage;
    float randNum;
    public float fallSpeed = 8.0f;

    public Sprite OneHits;
    public Sprite TwoHits;
    public Sprite ThreeHits;

    public Text ScoreText;
    public static int points;
    GameObject ball;

    void Start()
    {
        ball = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ball");
    }

    void Update()
    {
        ScoreText.text = "Score " + points;
        randNum = Random.Range(0f, 1f);

        if (hitPoint == 1)
        {
            this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = OneHits;
        }
        if (hitPoint == 2)
        {
            this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = TwoHits;
        }
        if (hitPoint == 3)
        {
            this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = ThreeHits;
        }
    }


    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("ball"))
        {
            ball = collision.gameObject;
            hitPoint--;
            points++;

            if (hitPoint <= 0)
            {
                Instantiate(explosion, transform.position, transform.rotation);

                if (randNum < percentage)
                {
                    Instantiate(heart, transform.position, transform.rotation);
                }
                Destroy(gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you all, I will take your suggestions and try to fix my problem. Cheers

Comment: @JosephTaliana if this answer solved your issue please mark it so others know :)